# How do you synthesize 1-fluoro-4-(tribromomethyl)benzene from toluene

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I got this question from an o-chem II exam which kinda puzzles me a bit[image: question]

My proposed path is:
[image]

which doesn't seem to be correct. Is there any other way within the knowledge of o-chem I & II?

Comment: Why do you think this is not correct? It is a bit old-tech but it will work. It is possible to directly fluorinate toluene, but you get a mixture of o and p  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8329385/

Comment: I am wondering that bromine reacts specifically with methyl, but my organic chemistry is very rusty.

Comment: @Poutnik under radical conditions it will

Comment: @Waylander I was being skeptical about the last step (bromonation), but seems like it was correct after all, thanks!

Comment: To complement a search in a reaction/literature database like Reaxys/Scifinder, there is an entry [p-Fluorobenzotribromide](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/70546827) with entries in sections literature and patents. Beside reference to the patent, double click on title of the patent reviews the patent ([example](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/patent/JP-2011098942-A)) including section 7 / linked molecules ([example](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/patent/JP-2011098942-A#section=Linked-Chemicals)). Although a search by patent can take long/be in part inaccessible by language/script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This route will work.

p-Nitrotoluene is the major product of toluene nitration and may be isolated by distillation and recrystallisation, procedure [here](https://www.oc-praktikum.de/nop/en/instructions/pdf/1001_en.pdf)

This recent [paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acsomega.1c02825) describes low temperature and light catalysed Balz-Schiemann conditions which are rather more user-friendly than some of the older procedures.

This [patent](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/patent/EP-0045430-A1) describes a method of brominating the p-F-toluene to the benzotrifluoride